# Multiple XIB error: Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I want to load different `.xib` for iPhone 4 and 5.

I have three files `FirstViewController.h`,`FirstViewController.m` and `FirstViewController.xib`
I have added one more empty `.xib` file for `iPhone 5` and named it `FirstViewController4Inch.xib`.

Here is my code snippet:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
        {
            self = [super initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController.xib" bundle:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            self = [super initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController4Inch.xib" bundle:nil];
        }
        return self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

When I run my app on both 3.5 and in 4 it gives the error:

```
Error:Could not load NIB in bundle:
```

Comment: You are assigning `self` more than once.  That cannot be right.

Comment: remove your .xib xtension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line

```
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
```

Also make sure that both .xibs have your class as file owner.

Comment: Do the FirstViewController4Inch.xib and FirstViewController.xib have FirstViewController as file owner?

Comment: Open the xib. On the right click the first cube (file owner) and in the inspector select the third tab (with the newspaper-like icon). In the Custom Class field, add FirstViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work:

```
- (id)init
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController4Inch" bundle:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

as long as you create it programmatically using:

```
myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
```

Comment: `- (id)init` method is not getting fired.

Comment: @Krunal Are you calling it as I suggested?

Comment: @Krunal OK so what mechanism is used to create the view controller?

Answer (score 1):

Leave out the .xib part.

```
self = [super initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method like this :

```
- (id)init
{
    self = (IS_IPHONE5() ? [super initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController4Inch" bundle:nil] : [super initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil]);

    if (self)
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

and use the macro `IS_IPHONE5()`

```
#define IS_IPHONE5()    ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
- (id)initForCustomScreen
{
    NSString *nibName = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480 ? @"FirstViewController" : @"FirstViewController4Inch");

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
    if (self) {

        // initialisation code
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a combination of Nickos and Maggie. Here is the merged solution which uses the View Controller Class name to provide the Nib name:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self)
    {
        NSString* nibName = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
        {
            self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
        }
        else 
        {
            self = [super initWithNibName:[nibName stringByAppendingString:@"4inch"] bundle:nil];
        }
        return self;
    }
    return self;
}
```